# Containerized Rails application in Swarm access containerized database in compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, mysql2

I have two virtual machines (VM) each machine is in a Docker Swarm environment, one VM has a mysql container running in docker-compose (for now let's say I can't move it to swarm), in the other machine I'm trying to connect a containerized rails app that is inside the swarm I'm using mysql2 gem to connect to the database however I'm having the following error:

`Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'bduser'@'10.0.13.248' (using password: YES)`

I have double checked the credentials, I also ran an alpine container in this VM where the rails is running, installed mysql and succesfully connected to the db in the other VM (was not in swarm though). I checked the ip address and I'm not sure where this came from, it is not the ip for the db's container.

Compose file for the database:

```
version: '3.4'
services:   
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    container_name: db-container
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysecurepassword
    command: --sql-mode STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION --max-connections 350
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql 
    healthcheck:
      test: mysqladmin ping --silent
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
```

How can I successfully connect the rails app to the db's container, considering that the db is running using docker-compose and the rails is in a swarm in another VM?

Answer (score 0):

If docker swarm mode is reduced to its core functionality: it adds `overlay` networks to docker. Also called vxlans these are software defined networks that containers can be attached to. overlay networks are the mechanisim that allow containers on different hosts to communicate with each other.

With that in mind, even if you otherwise treat your docker swarm as a set of discreet docker hosts on which you run compose stacks, you can nonetheless get services to communicate completely privately.

First, on a manager node, create an overlay network with a well known name:-

`docker network create application --driver overlay`

Now in your compose files, deployed as compose stacks on different nodes, you should be able to reference that network:

```yaml
# deployed on node1
networks:
  application:
    external: true

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql-password
  networks:
  - application
  volumes:
  - ./mysql/:/var/lib/mysql
```

```yaml
# deployed on node2
networks:
  application:
    external: true
services:
  my-rails-app:
    image: my-rails:dev
    build:
      context: src
    networks:
    - application
    volumes:
    - ./data:/data
```

etc.